# WampServer 3.2.3 cant access Lan Network,

Tags: php, apache, http, wampserver

i cant access my wampserver machine, this is my specifications
windows 10
wampserver 3.2.3.3 64bits
Apache 2.4.46

i have edited this file "D:\Programs\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf",
and replaced "Require local" to "Require all granted", below is the complete text in the file

```
    # Virtual Hosts
    #
    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName localhost
      ServerAlias localhost
      DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
      <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
      </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

and i have restarted all the services, but i cant access the server from other machine connected to the same network

The ip machine that has wampserver is "192.168.1.11", so in the other computer i entered in the browser that ip "192.168.1.11" and keeps loading about 4 minutes and stops.

can anybody help, is there something else i have to do?, thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the solution and Wampserver was not the problem.
The problem is the Windows 10 firewall that was blocking the network access.
so these are the steps to allow the network access:

```
  1.- In windows 10 go to Menu "Firewall and network Protection"
  2.- click on "Allow an app through firewall" option, it opens a window with title "allowed apps"
  3.- Click on button "Change Settings" (You have to have administrator rights to do this)
  4.- Click on "Allow another app", and browse to your wamp installation and search for httpd.exe of apache, in my case "D:\Programs\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46\bin\httpd.exe", and click on button add "Add"
  5.- and in the columns "Private and Public", check the checkbox for "Public" column and last click on button "Ok" at the bottom of the window
  6.- Now you can access to Wampserver Homepage from another machine in the same network
```

This works but it is strange, because i didnt have to do these steps with wamp early versions
Hope this help to others with the same problem